# SQLITE compiled for NW.js - One command for SQL CRUD

Tags: javascript, sqlite, node-webkit

I am trying to figure this out, but I really need some insight.

I have Express.js application that runs either on sqlite3 or on SQLserver. depending if it is run on desktop then it uses sqlite (NW.js) and when run on web it uses SQL server.

I am trying to use the same code base, as much as possible. So far I have a method that provides connection to the applicaiton. I use [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql) SQLServer module for Express.js

SQLserver has method query, that accepts pure SQL statement (CRUD) and does whatever it needs to do.

My plan is to use the same SQL statements for both versions.
But it seems that it not the case with sqlite3 (compiled for NW.js). It has different commands such as run, all, each...

1. Is there a SINGLE (like in SQLserver) command in SQLITE that will accept raw statement and work on it, without using run, and all. I mean, something like:

   "INSERT INTO MyTable(MyName) VALUES ('John').

If there is, I would simply add a new method with the same name "query", and both versions would work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There was a slight difference between the way how the SQLite queries operate, mainly those that change the state (Update, new...) of the db.

After some research I have found a great [ORM tool](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/), that I implemented in the project, and now my code is totally agnostic regarding the DB 'dialect'.

Hopefully this might help someone as well.